# Certain pages are moving about 5 pixels over

Tags: html, css

I have a sample of the new version of my non profits website up at http://www.blazingoctopuss.com

Using the top nav bar, when you go between index and about us or between index and donate, the entire page shifts about 5 pixels to the side.

However, when you go from index to services the page stays put. Also when you go between about us and donate, the page stays in one place.

So there is something about about us, and donate that is different than index and services but I cannot see what it is. They are all using the same style sheet and I can't see anything different in the way I've called the pages.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance for giving it a look!

Comment: Are you talking about the effect of the scrollbar?

Comment: Wow....I'm an idiot. Yep, thats what it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It shifts the exact amount required to add a vertical scroll-bar (a lot more than 5 pixels, but different in every browser) whenever content exceeds the height of the window.  This is normal and expected behavior, there is nothing wrong with your design in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

just as Sparky 672 said. This is normal.

However, if the transition bothers you, add a (disabled) scroll-bar to the pages that don't need one by adding this line to the css:

```
body { overflow: auto }
```

now there will no page "jumps" when navigating the site.

Comment: The problem with this suggestion is that you'll also get a horizontal as well as a vertical "disabled" or ghost scroll-bar where you don't need one.  IMHO, I believe that the browsers' default behavior should be left alone.

Comment: Close, he'd need to add `overflow-y: scroll`, "auto" doesn't display a scrollbar until needed, so you must use "scroll" to force a scrollbar.  And "overflow-y" adds only the vertical scrollbar.

Comment: @gilly3, that's what I was going for. good looking. I have used that technique in the past, but it is an essential element - IMHO - in pages with dynamic height. if you know the user could expand a drop-down and create the scroll bar "jump," i believe you should always include the vert. scroll bar.